# What is the linq equivalent to the SQL IN operator

Tags: c#, sql, linq, contains

With linq I have to check if a value of a row is present in an array.
The equivalent of the sql query:

```
WHERE ID IN (2,3,4,5)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

.Contains

```
var resultset = from x in collection where new[] {2,3,4,5}.Contains(x) select x
```

Of course, with your simple problem, you could have something like:

```
var resultset = from x in collection where x >= 2 && x <= 5 select x
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: `int[] does not contain a definition of contains`.

Comment: Could be because System.Linq not included ?

Answer (score 31):

Perform the equivalent of an SQL IN with [IEnumerable.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx).

```
var idlist = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var result = from x in source
          where idlist.Contains(x.Id)
          select x;
```

Answer (score 12):

```
db.SomeTable.Where(x => new[] {2,3,4,5}.Contains(x));
```

or

```
from x in db.SomeTable
where new[] {2,3,4,5}.Contains(x)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be using x.<propertyname> that matches with the datatype to search, in this case, integers. like db.sometable.where(x => new[]  {1,2}.Contains(x.Id));

Answer (score 10):

Intersect and Except are a little more concise and will probably be a bit faster too.

IN

```
collection.Intersect(new[] {2,3,4,5});
```

NOT IN

```
collection.Except(new[] {2,3,4,5});
```

or

Method syntax for IN

```
collection.Where(x => new[] {2,3,4,5}.Contains(x));
```

and NOT IN

```
collection.Where(x => !(new[] {2,3,4,5}.Contains(x)));
```

Answer (score 3):

An `IEnumerable<T>.Contains(T)` statement should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A very basic example using .Contains()

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++)
{
    list.Add(k);
}

int[] conditionList = new int[]{2,3,4};

var a = (from test in list
         where conditionList.Contains(test)
         select test);
```

Comment: You could clean this up a lot by changing your `for` loop to `IEnumerable<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);`

Comment: Point taken. +1 But to be fair, I was just writing code I knew would work without needing to test it :)

Answer (score 2):

The above situations work when the `Contains` function is used against primitives, but what if you are dealing with objects (e.g. `myListOrArrayOfObjs.Contains(efObj)`)?

I found a solution!  Convert your `efObj` into a `string`, thats separated by `_` for each field (you can almost think of it as a CSV representation of your obj)

An example of such may look like this:

```
     var reqAssetsDataStringRep = new List<string>();

        foreach (var ra in onDemandQueueJobRequest.RequestedAssets)
        {
            reqAssetsDataStringRep.Add(ra.RequestedAssetId + "_" + ra.ImageId);
        }

        var requestedAssets = await (from reqAsset in DbContext.RequestedAssets
                                     join image in DbContext.Images on reqAsset.ImageId equals image.Id
                                     where reqAssetsDataStringRep.Contains(reqAsset.Id + "_" + image.Id)
                                     select reqAsset
                                           ).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write help-method:

```
    public bool Contains(int x, params int[] set) {
        return set.Contains(x);
    }
```

and use short code:

```
    var resultset = from x in collection
                    where Contains(x, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                    select x;
```

Answer (score -1):

Following is a generic extension method that can be used to search a value within a list of values:

```cs
public static bool In<T>(this T searchValue, params T[] valuesToSearch)
{
    if (valuesToSearch == null)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < valuesToSearch.Length; i++)
        if (searchValue.Equals(valuesToSearch[i]))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

This can be used as:

```cs
int i = 5;
i.In(45, 44, 5, 234); // Returns true

string s = "test";
s.In("aa", "b", "c"); // Returns false
```

This is handy in conditional statements.