# Where clause against multiple options

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, listbox, linq-to-entities

Is there any "IN" keyword available in Linq to entities syntax ? I have a listbox where multiple items are added. I want to search for those items in db. My query looks like this:

```
 var result = context.data_vault
                      .Where(d => d.STATE == lstStates.SelectedItem.Text).OrderBy(d=>d.dv_id)
                      .Skip(e.NewPageIndex * GridView1.PageSize)
                      .Take(GridView1.PageSize)
                      .ToList();
```

I want `d => d.STATE == lstStates.Items`. How to change it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334327/what-is-the-linq-equivalent-to-the-sql-in-operator possible dupe

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
string[] arr = listview.Items
                       .Cast<ListItem>()
                       .Select(i => i.Text) // or .Value
                       .ToArray();

db.Where(d => arr.Contains(d.STATE);
```

should be translated into the query:

```
... WHERE STATE IN ('your', 'array', 'items')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = context.data_vault
                      .Where(d => lstStates.Items.Contains(d.STATE)).OrderBy(d=>d.dv_id)
                      .Skip(e.NewPageIndex * GridView1.PageSize)
                      .Take(GridView1.PageSize)
                      .ToList();
```

Here,

```
lstStates is List<string>
```

Comment: [ListItemCollection.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.contains.aspx) accepts ListItem not string

Comment: @abatishchev Ok, agreed. I had assumed that lstStates is List<string> (:

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.Any()` or `.Contains()` syntax

example something like this:

```
select d from context.Data
Where ListofIdsFromUI.Any(d.Id)
select d
```