# How to check for null on Nullable types using Linq expression in Realm?

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin, realm, realm-net

I want to get all elements where the Modified property isn't set but can't seem to get it to work with Realm.

Sample Code:

```
public class FooModel : RealmObject
{
  public DateTimeOffset? Modified { get; set; }
}

...

public List<FooModel> GetAllUnmodified()
{
  var realm = Realm.GetInstance();

  //doesn't work
  var result1 = realm.All<FooModel>().Where(model => model.Modified == null).ToList();

  //doesn't work
  var result2 = realm.All<FooModel>().Where(model => !model.Modified.HasValue).ToList();

  //doesn't work
  DateTimeOffset? testValue = null;
  var result3 = realm.All<FooModel>().Where(model => model.Modified == testValue).ToList();

  //doesn't work
  var result4 = realm.All<FooModel>().Where(model => model.Modified == default(DateTimeOffset?)).ToList();

  return result1;
}
```

Always getting `System.NotSupportedException: The rhs of the binary operator 'Equal' should be a constant or closure variable expression.` or `System.NotSupportedException: The member 'HasValue' is not supported`

Did I miss anything? Is there a good way to see what actually is supported by Realm's Linq?

Using Realm Xamarin v0.77.1 on Android

**EDIT:**

I did try [creating a linq expression tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675419/realm-xamarin-throws-error-the-method-contains-is-not-supported-same-for-an) as suggested by a commenter. This resulted in a `System.MissingMethodException: Method 'RealmResults'1.get_Provider' not found.` exception.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. After giving it a try I couldn't get it to work. I get the following exception: `System.MissingMethodException: Method 'RealmResults'1.get_Provider' not found.`. So it compiles fine but throws an error at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is missing and high priority: [#517](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/517). We are very aware that we have a number of LINQ shortcomings, we are looking into that whole area, including writing a summary about what features are supported, in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Note for anyone seeing this later - this feature was added in version 0.77.0 and is live in the current 0.78.1.

We now support comparison to null.

```
public class Person : RealmObject
{
    public bool? IsAmbivalent { get; set; }
...
_realm.All<Person>().Where(p => p.IsAmbivalent == null);
```

Or, for string properties, also checking:

```
_realm.All<Person>().Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.OptionalAddress));
```

See [unit tests for more examples](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/release/0.78.0/Tests/IntegrationTests.Shared/RealmResults/SimpleLINQtests.cs#L233)