# Best way to comapare Phone contacts with Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, cordova-plugins

I am using Corodva Contacts Plugin to fetch the local phone contacts its working great,Now i need to compare it with database,I am not using local db, I am using sql server 2012 and I have written some back-end code with WEBAPI.Its taking lot of time to compare. I need some alternative solution to it. Kindly suggest below is my code.

```
         //Javascript///

  var phoneNumberCollection = new Array();

  function showContacts() {

var options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = "";
  options.multiple = true;
  options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id,navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName,  navigator.contacts.fieldType.name, navigator.contacts.fieldType.phoneNumbers];
options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
   var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
   navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}

 function onSuccess(contacts) 
  {
     // here i have all contacts and i am pushing each number into       "phoneNumberCollection" array//
  }

 function onError(err)
 { 
 }

  self.GetContactsData = function () {
    self.PhoneNumberCollection = phoneNumberCollection;
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({mobilecollection:  self.PhoneNumberCollection,}),
        url: Url + 'api/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx',
        success: function (data) {
            self.items($.map(data, function (item) {
                return new ContactsModel(item);
            }));
        },
        error: function (err, type, httpStatus) {
         }
    })

}

     //Web API
  [HttpPost]
    public  IHttpActionResult GetContacts(JObject jsonData)
    {
        try
        {
            if (jsonData != null)
            {
                dynamic json = jsonData;

                string[] mobilenumberCollection = json.mobilecollection.ToObject<string[]>();
    //here i am getting Mobile collection and i am comparing each number with DB. i need some alternative sugggestion for this
   var getContacts = CBFriends.getAllcontacts(mobilenumberCollection, deviceUID);
                if (getAllContacts != null)
                {
                    return Ok(getAllContacts);
                }
                else { return NotFound(); }

            }
            else {
                return BadRequest();}
           }
        catch (Exception)
        { }      
       }
```

Comment: It's depends on many parameters, which field you check in DB only id or all fields in contacts?

Comment: @ygalbel Thanks for your time, I have column called Mobile Number in my DB so I need to check only one column, I am comparing only the local phone number with Database Mobile Number kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `IN` operator in sql server.

You can send all phone numbers in one query and get ones that not exists in db.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337864/1543596) answer, to see how to achieve this in c#.

Comment: Thanks For your time, I saw that,But i am using Linq to fetch the data,is there any example using Linq to sql

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334327/what-is-the-linq-equivalent-to-the-sql-in-operator)

Comment: var MobileNumberExsitDB = dbContext.UserTable.Where(m => m.mobileNumber == mobilenumber).FirstOrDefault(); i am using query like this, mobilenumber which will in foreach loop contains one number at  time

Comment: I need to get user Details related to existing mobilenumber in DB,so i can use for binding

Comment: You have to made one query for all the phone numbers.

Comment: 1, create an array with all phoneNumbers 2. run query like this: dbContext.UserTable.Where(m => phoneArray.Contains(m));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138818/discussion-between-kitty-sarvaj-and-ygalbel).

Comment: https://github.com/kittysarvaj/Compare-Contacts/blob/master/.gitignore, i have created the new file in github,please suggest me

Comment: var numbersThatNotExistsInDB = mobileNumbers.Where(!usersThatExsitInDB.Any(a => a.mobileNumber == a)).ToList(); i am getting the error ,which say "operand==" cannot applied to string type UserTable

Comment: Sorry, change to `var numbersThatNotExistsInDB = mobileNumbers.Where(!usersThatExsitInDB.Any(a => a.mobileNumber == mobileNumbers)).ToList();`

Comment: still it didnt work,i think its comparing single value a.mobileNumber with list values

Comment: Fixed. Check `var numbersThatNotExistsInDB = mobileNumbers.Where(n => !usersThatExsitInDB.Any(a => a.mobileNumber == n)).ToList();`